# duplicate key error in entitymanager with correct object to persist

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby, entitymanager

I have the following entity TitleScreenFormat  and when i do `entitymanager.commit` 
I getting the following error

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key
value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified
by 'SQL130418144233630' defined on 'S1_TITLESCREENFORMAT'. Error Code:
20000 Call: INSERT INTO s1_TitleScreenFormat
(titlescreenformat_titleid, titlescreenformat_format,
titlescreenformat_deliveryformat, TITLE_title_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [TitleId1, Format1, DeliveryFormat1, null]
```

This is the entity with the keys

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "s1_TitleScreenFormat")
    public class TitleScreenFormat 
    {
        @Id 
        @Column(name = "titlescreenformat_titleid", length = 128)    
        private String TitleId;

        @Id 
        @Column(name = "titlescreenformat_deliveryformat", length = 128)    
        private String DeliveryFormat;

        @Id 
        @Column(name = "titlescreenformat_format", length = 128)    
        private String Format;


        private Title Title;
```

And this is the instance of the object which i have want to persist

```
[0] TitleScreenFormat  (id=81)  
    DeliveryFormat  "DeliveryFormat1" (id=87)   
    Format  "Format1" (id=88)   
    Title   null    
    TitleId "TitleId1" (id=89)  
[1] TitleScreenFormat  (id=83)  
    DeliveryFormat  "DeliveryFormat2" (id=90)   
    Format  "Format2" (id=91)   
    Title   null    
    TitleId "TitleId2" (id=92)  
[2] TitleScreenFormat  (id=84)  
    DeliveryFormat  "DeliveryFormat3" (id=93)   
    Format  "Format3" (id=94)   
    Title   null    
    TitleId "TitleId3" (id=95)  
[3] TitleScreenFormat  (id=85)  
    DeliveryFormat  "DeliveryFormat4" (id=96)   
    Format  "Format4" (id=97)   
    Title   null    
    TitleId "TitleId4" (id=98)  
[4] TitleScreenFormat  (id=86)  
    DeliveryFormat  "DeliveryFormat5" (id=99)   
    Format  "Format5" (id=100)  
    Title   null    
    TitleId "TitleId5" (id=101)
```

in the persistence.xml file i use the following configuration

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
```

And Im using Derby DB.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Are you deploying the app in a server like glassfish?  If so, Glassfish intercepts the EclipseLink DDL properties and uses its own Java2DB feature, so check the scripts created and the logs to see if the tables were dropped correctly as expected.

Comment: Enable logging and check that the table are being dropped and create and no duplicate insert is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting same values again in the DB.
Just check once in your DB before persisting these values, if they are already existing there.

Alternatively you can change these values and try committing again.

Comment: But the drop and create tables should create the new instances in every time...dont you think ?